# Cygwin make command throws a lot of 'undefined reference to' errors

Tags: gcc, build, g++, cygwin

I have been trying to install FORM (https://github.com/vermaseren/form), and using the make command in cygwin in order to build it. However, I get the following error:

[image]

which is only the last part of the error, since the whole thing is approx. 10 times longer, but also filled with 'undefined reference to' errors.

My guess is that g++ has to be used instead of gcc, which is also installed in my case, but I don't know which command is the g++ equivalent for 'make'. Are there any other solutions that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

When you ask for support you should report the exact commands you gave and their output as text in line not as picture.

Please remember that `Make` calls the compilers, the compilers are producing the error you see. The root cause is that you have not properly configured the source for a compilation on Cygwin.

The following is the build sequence that I used and that produced the proper binaries.

```
$ wget https://github.com/vermaseren/form/releases/download/v4.3.1/form-4.3.1.tar.gz
...
2024-02-08 21:40:53 (3.29 MB/s) - ‘form-4.3.1.tar.gz’ saved [1470480/1470480]

$ tar -xf form-4.3.1.tar.gz
$ cd form-4.3.1
$ autoreconf
$ ./configure
...
##################### CONFIGURATION #####################

FORM 4.3.1

Compiling for: Opteron Cygwin (LP64 POSIX)

Optionally linked libraries:
    gmp
    zlib

The following executables can be compiled:
    form       scalar version (native)
    tform      multi-threaded version (native)

Type 'make <executable name>' in the source directory to
build a specific version. Type 'make' to build all.

Type 'make install' to install the executables in
    /usr/local/bin
and the man page in
    /usr/local/share/man

Type 'make check' to run automatic tests.

Available documentation:
    doxygen    ( html dvi ps pdf )
    manual     ( html dvi ps pdf )

Type 'make <format>' in the directories doc/manual or
doc/doxygen to generate the respective documentation with
the specified format.

#########################################################

$ make
..
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/form-4.3.1'


$ find . -name "*.exe"
./sources/form.exe
./sources/tform.exe
```

The build was not perfect but not so bad

```
$ make check
....
Finished in 97.9087595 seconds.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
227 tests, 850 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
99.5595% passed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2.32 tests/s, 8.68 assertions/s
FAIL: check-help.sh
FORM 4.3.1 (Apr 11 2023, v4.3.1) 64-bits
  0.053333 form units in 5.406 seconds (cpu time)
  corresponding to 35.51 form units per hour
PASS: benchmark-fu.sh
==========================================================
1 of 2 tests failed
Please report to https://github.com/vermaseren/form/issues
==========================================================
make[2]: *** [Makefile:340: check-TESTS] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/form-4.3.1/check'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:465: check-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/form-4.3.1/check'
make: *** [Makefile:406: check-recursive] Error 1
```